# How to map REAL Datatype in SQL with Decimal? in C#

Tags: c#, sql, llblgen

I have written a stored procedure which returns one of the value as `REAL` datatype since it is referring to some old database table.

I want to convert/map this value to a `decimal?` type in C#. However, I get an error:

> Specified cast not valid

when running this code:

```
item.SludgeCapacity =v.Field<decimal?>("SludgeCapacity");
```

Does anyone have an optimised solution?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings

Answer (score 0):

try

```
item.SludgeCapacity = Convert.ToDecimal(v.Field("SludgeCapacity"));
```